# Will replacing GRUB with BURG increase my system's boot time?

Tags: boot, grub2, burg

I guess BURG will require more time to start, because it displays some eye-candy graphics. If I replaced GRUB with BURG, would the time required to boot into Ubuntu be significantly longer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use burg since 1 year. It works well and I have never noticed a difference in boot time between grub and burg.

Comment: Agree. I've used BURG & there is no significant lag.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I havent tried out BURG.

Googling for Burg tells me that it is only a decorator for GRUB. That said, it will not do anything to change how your computer boots. So, coming back to your question, IMO, the time required for booting will not increase. Since burg only decorates GRUB, you might face a tiny lag before viewing BURG, but I reckon it wont me something you will notice.

Comment: BURG is not a decorator for GRUB. Its a decorated *replacement* for GRUB. Its an independent bootloder, not and *add-on*